# Looking for a substring in an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I've put the id's from all checked checkboxes into an array and converted it to a string. Now I want to loop over all the labels in my HTML and see if value of the `for` attribute matches with something in the string of all ids, and if this matches change the css of the label. Thank you in advance.

```
var $all_labels = $('.filter-choices label')

$all_labels.each(function(){
      var self_item = $(this)
      if( self_item.attr('for').is(checked_items_ids_string) === true){
      self_item.css('color','white')
   }
});
```

Comment: checked_items_ids_string?? is ?

Comment: Why convert the array to a string?  You could have just looped your array of ids and got the labels with `$("[for='" + id + "']")`

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón This was an array with with all the id's that I've collected and transformed into a string, but as Pete said I was able to do this without converting the array to a string. I almost got the solution thank you guys for your reply

Comment: ÁlvaroTouzón This was an array with with all the id's that I've collected and transformed into a string, but as @Pete said I was able to do this without converting the array to a string. I almost got the solution thank you guys for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First I've put the id's from all checked checkboxes into an array and
>   converted it so a string
>
> Now I want to loop over all the labels in my HTML and see if value of
>   the for attribute matches with something in the string of all ids.

Try with

```
var checkedItems = []; //assuming this is already populated
$( "label[for]" ).each( function(){
   var idVal = $(this).attr( "for" );
   if ( $("#" + idVal).length > 0 && checkedItems.indexOf( idVal ) != -1 )
   {
      //element with id exists
      $(this).css('color','white')
   }
})
```

Comment: Hey @gurvinder372 thank you for your solution. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach will be helpful also:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  $('input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      $(this).prev('label').css("color", "red")
    else
      $(this).prev('label').css("color", "black")
  })
})
```

```html
<label for="i1">Input 1: </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="i1">
<br>
<label for="i1">Input 1: </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="i1">
<br>
<label for="i1">Input 1: </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="i1">
<br>
<label for="i1">Input 1: </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="i1">
<br>
<label for="i1">Input 1: </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="i1">
<br>
<button>Change labels</button>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
```

Comment: @Waldemarlce this solution would have worked too , thank you for your input